# Unable to use scp with a bash alias

Tags: scp, bash-alias

This code does not work:

```
scp ~/Desktop/favicon.ico nameOfBashAlias:/public_html/mySite/templates/blog/
```

The alias is:

```
alias nameOfBashAlias='ssh myUsername@11.11.11.111'
```

How do I solve this problem?

#### Edit

Is something similar to the following code possible, like running many instances of `bash`?

```
scp ~/Desktop/favicon.ico (nameOfBashAlias)>:/public_html/mySite/templates/blog/
```

I did not get the above code to work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using a Bash alias for what you are trying to accomplish. You can just enter all the information into SSH's config file and be done with it. Read the man page for `ssh_config` if you are curious where these come from. You can do some neat things with `ssh_config`

The file is located here `~/.ssh/config`

Use your favorite editor and create the file and then adjust these to your situation.

```
Host nameOfBashAlias
HostName 11.11.11.11
User myUsername
Port 22
```

You are now setup to issue the following command:

```
$ ssh nameOfBashAlias
```

Something I bet you didn't know is how integrated this all is. Now that you have this setup, the following commands also work

```
$ scp /some/file nameOfBashAlias:/path/to/storage/location/
```

No more remembering that scp uses "-P" for port and ssh uses "-p". Also this "alias" also works in OS X gui apps like Transmit.

OpenSSH obtains configuration data from the following sources in the following order:

1. command-line options
2. user's configuration file `~/.ssh/config`
3. system-wide configuration file `/etc/ssh_config`

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with your. I am nowadays using that method too, since it syncs a lot better with other system and other tools.

Comment: doesnot work for me on MacOSX

Comment: @JabranSaeed Please, open a new question or here a community wiki as an answer about your case with a piece of information about your OS, version, shell etc. Please, provide also link about your challenge here in comment. This thread is relevant for GNU scp.

Comment: FWIW this does appear to work on OS X (at least it did on mine, El Capitain 10.11.6)

Answer (score 5):

`scp` doesn't run bash.  You would need to run this:

```
 scp ~/Desktop/favicon.ico 11.11.11.111:/public_html/mySite/templates/blog/
```

If all you have is the alias and the above code is not possible for you, consider running it like this:

```
nameOfBashAlias cat /public_html/mySite/templates/blog/ > ~/Desktop/favicon.ico
```

In this way, you're actually invoking `ssh` and directing the file content to a file on disk.  This can be written the other way for uploads.

Comment: The first command should be  scp ~/Desktop/favicon.ico username@11.11.11.111:/public_html/mySite/templates/blog/

Answer (score 3):

Aliases are substituted when they are the **first** word of a bash command.  Your alias appears at the start of the third word.

I would use a shell variable for this.

```
blah='myUsername@11.11.11.111'
scp ~/Desktop/favicon.ico ${blah}:/public_html/mySite/templates/blog/
```

Btw, I think your original alias shouldn't have ssh in it.  And the last code sample has a > in it that looks wrong too.

Comment: @mataap: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

No, your examples will not work, because that is not how `BASH` aliases work. I suggest you use a variable. Put this in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` [whichever you use]:

`site="user@site.com"`

then in your terminal, this will work:
`scp favicon.ico $site:/dir/`

Or you could write a script like I do for my iPod. in my bashrc I have `ipod=192.168.2.60`, then in my script I `source ~/.bashrc` so it gets my variables in the script, then in the script: `scp $1 $ipod`
the downside is I'd have to edit the script to do recursive. and I can only do 1 file. but when I need either of those I usually use `scp` directly from the terminal!

~Matt